# Python - Dictionary - max value and according key with function and for-loop

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop, key-value

I want to get the max value and the according to key from a dictionary with a function and for loop. Heres my code:

```
Autolager = {'Audi' : 9, 'BMW' : 11, 'Mercedes' : 8}

def Maxlagerbestand(Autolager):  
    MaxAutoValue = 0  
    MaxAutoName = None  
    for i in Autolager:  
        if Autolager[i] > MaxAutoValue:  
            MaxAutoValue = Autolager[i]  
            MaxAutoName = [k for k, v in Autolager.items() if v == MaxAutoValue]  
        return (MaxAutoValue, MaxAutoName)      
print (Maxlagerbestand(Autolager))
```

The output is then (9, ['Audi']) but its supposed to be (11, ['BMW])

I even checked it without the function:

```
MaxAutoValue = 0  
for i in Autolager:  
    if Autolager[i] > MaxAutoValue:  
        MaxAutoValue = Autolager[i]  
print (MaxAutoValue)
```

Here the output is correctly given with 11.

What went wrong in my above code? I am thankful for any hints.

Comment: You immediately return at the end of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the `return (MaxAutoValue, MaxAutoName)` inside the for loop, and not after the for loop has completed.

```
Autolager = {'Audi' : 9, 'BMW' : 11, 'Mercedes' : 8}

def Maxlagerbestand(Autolager):  
    MaxAutoValue = 0  
    MaxAutoName = None  
    for i in Autolager:  
        if Autolager[i] > MaxAutoValue:  
            MaxAutoValue = Autolager[i]  
            MaxAutoName = [k for k, v in Autolager.items() if v == MaxAutoValue]  
    return (MaxAutoValue, MaxAutoName)      
print (Maxlagerbestand(Autolager))
```

Also I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `[k for k, v in Autolager.items() if v == MaxAutoValue]`. Wouldn't replacing that with `i` or `[i]` be easier?

Comment: Ah, i understand. Could have seen that myself, i guess. Thank you very much for your help! Its now working.
I also changed the value of the variable MaxAutoName to i, it had worked just fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

A classic one: You *immediately* return at the end of the `for` loop. So that means you return the result maximum after the *first* iteration. It thus has not yet evaluated *all* elements.

That being said, this can be improved a lot by using `max(..)`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

max_kv = max(autolager.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

This will result in a 2-tuple containing the key-value combination with the largest value, so:

```
>>> max(autolager.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
('BMW', 11)
```

if you want to obtain *all* keys with this value, we can do a second run through the dictionary:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def maxlagerbestand(autolager):
    max_v = max(autolager.values())
    return max_v, [k for k, v in autolager.items() if v == max_v]
```

Here this then returns:

```
>>> maxlagerbestand(autolager) 
(11, ['BMW'])
```

For an empty dictionary (`{}`) the above will error. We can add a `default=` value to the `max(..)` to return a value given the dictionary is empty:

```
def maxlagerbestand(autolager):
    max_v = max(autolager.values(), default=None)
    return max_v, [k for k, v in autolager.items() if v == max_v]
```

For an empty dictionary this will then return:

```
>>> maxlagerbestand({}) 
(None, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions as well. I also tried the max function on the problem and it worked fine. Just wanted to challenge myself, to do it with a for loop, since iam absolutely new to python and programming.

Answer (score 1):

Although Mark's answer would work you could simplify the code

```
Autolager = {'Audi' : 9, 'BMW' : 11, 'Mercedes' : 8}

def Maxlagerbestand(Autolager):  
    MaxAutoValue = 0  
    MaxAutoName = None  
    for key, value in Autolager.items():  
        if value > MaxAutoValue:  
            MaxAutoValue = value 
            MaxAutoName = key 
    return (MaxAutoValue, MaxAutoName)  

print (Maxlagerbestand(Autolager))
```

Comment: Thanks also for your suggestions. I tried it but had to change v and k to value and key, to get it working. Otherwise it tells me, that v and k are not defined.

Comment: @MikeTwain you are right I forgot to replace k and v for key and value to make it more readable, I have edited the answer, Thank you.